Is BLS12-381 precompile now available on mainnet?
I read in this article that EIP-2537 was included in the Dencun upgrade. So can I now use it in mainnet? If so then could you link resources on how.

Not yet available on mainnet: Dencun does not include EIP-2537.
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-7569 lists the EIPs included in Dencun.
